# Can't get the object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in Slider concept in MVC. My code in ascx file is,

```
 $(function () {
    alert('a');
    var List = $('select#ScaleList').selectToUISlider().next();
    alert(List);
    fixToolTipColor();
});

<%=Html.DropDownList("CList", null, "-Select Scale-", new { id = "ScaleList", Style = "display:none" })%>
```

In firefox, the above code is working fine. In IE, I can't get the object for      `"$('select#ScaleList').selectToUISlider().next();"`......It's showing Invalid argument.

How to get this...

Comment: Can you give an example snippet in jsfiddle or somewhere. Or slightly more information.

Comment: i had used selectToUISlider.js file for slider.

Comment: while opening my page, i should show my slider. from this " var List = $('select#ScaleList').selectToUISlider().next();" it will go the control. Here, i want to get the object. which is working fine in Firefox, but not in IE...

Comment: @RobinHood - The issue is likely in `selectToUISlider.js` can you post the content or link to it?

Comment: how can i attach a file here...?

Comment: Here is the link...http://code.google.com/p/aus-e-stage/source/browse/trunk/networks-ui/assets/javascript/libraries/selectToUISlider.jQuery.js?r=859

Comment: I am getting the error in, jquery-1.3.2.js as "Invalid Argument"..here is the js file link...http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.js&can=2&q=

Comment: in that js file, in this part i am getting the error....."---
  name = name.replace(/-([a-z])/ig, function(all, letter){
   return letter.toUpperCase();
  });

  if ( set )
   elem[ name ] = value;

  return elem[ name ]; -------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
$(function () {
    alert('a');
    var $List = $('select#ScaleList');
    $List.selectToUISlider().next();
    alert($List);
    fixToolTipColor();
});
```

just in case either of those methods are returning something other than your select in a jQuery object.

Comment: Its not working...I am getting the error in jquery-1.3.2.js as "Invalid Argument"..here is the js file link...http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.js&can=2&q=

Comment: in that js file, in this part i am getting the error....."--- name = name.replace(/-([a-z])/ig, function(all, letter){ return letter.toUpperCase(); }); if ( set ) elem[ name ] = value; return elem[ name ]; -------

Comment: if you're getting errors in jquery it's very unlikely to be jquery's fault. the error may occur in jquery code at runtime but the cause is most likely your incorrect usage.